# Node: internal modules not found

Tags: node.js, express, axios, node-modules

I am trying to run my express server in node that I have used in the past and I am getting the follow error in VSCode:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/valemich/Desktop/code/src/vscode/calls_sales/start'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1060:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:905:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

I am on a MACOS Ventura  using Node version v.19.5.0 and here is my package.json. Should I uninstall node completely and reinstall?  Do I have node installed in the wrong folder? I am completely at a loss for what the issue is.

```
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ngrok": "^4.3.3"
  }
```

and my server file is as follows:

```
/* eslint-disable object-shorthand */
/* eslint-disable comma-dangle */
/* eslint-disable semi */
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios').default;
// const Airtable = require('airtable');
// const base = new Airtable({ apiKey: `${process.env.AIRTABLE_TOKEN}` }).base(
//  `${process.env.AIRTABLE_CRM_ID}`
//  );

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) =>
  res.send(`
  <html>
    <head><title>Success!</title></head>
    <body>
      <h1>You did it!</h1>
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/XreQmk7ETCak0/giphy.gif" alt="Cool kid doing thumbs up" />
    </body>
  </html>
`)
);

app.post(`${process.env.AIRTABLE1_WEBHOOKS_URL}`, (req, res) => {
  // TODO: Update the base to show call date, call time, and questions
  // TODO: Create API to Calendly to find out who is assigned the call and the event name. Then post back again with information
  // TODO: duplicate this information to post to Slack as well (depending on event name to which channel it posts to.)
  const eventUrl = req.body.payload.event;
  const event = eventUrl.split('/')[4];
  console.log(event);
  const questions = req.body.payload.questions_and_answers;
  const question = [];
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  for (i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    question.push(questions[i].question, questions[i].answer);
    console.log(question);
  }

  // const content = `:wave: ${username} just starred ${repoName} :taco: :rocket:`;
  // const avatarUrl = req.body.sender.avatar_url;
  axios
    .post(process.env.AIRTABLE2_WEBHOOKS_URL, {
      content: content,
      embeds: [
        {
          image: {
            url: avatarUrl,
          },
        },
      ],
    })
    .then((airTableResponse) => {
      console.log('Success!');
      res.status(204).send();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(`Error sending to AirTable: ${err}`));
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500);
  res.send({ error: error });
  console.error(error.stack);
  next(error);
});

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
);
```

Comment: It might be using a different version of node.js, try deleting node_modules and package-lock file, then run npm i

Comment: still have the same errors how can I uninstall everything and start over I can't figure out what I did wrong